# Error displaying Json in text box C# form

Tags: c#, .net, json, forms

I´m using `Newton Json.NET` to deserialize a simple Json and display the resulting string into a `TextBox` in a `C#` form.

The problem is that I would like to append other data to each deserialized part. This is the well-formed string I have that is printed in the debug terminal.

[image]

`BEGIN 12234 ....Homer Simpson$$$$ 123456` are all data that I appended to the Json.

So far, so good. However, the data displayed on the form text box look like this:
[image]

Note that the text is unaligned and the appended part is in wrong positions.

This is the code I used to get the `json`:

```
var DJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(obj);

string foot = DJson[0].name.ToString();
string ret = "BEGIN 123456 " + DJson.ToString() + "...." + foot + "$$$$" + "123456";
return ret;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a right-to-left formatting problem. Change your `TextBox.RightToLeft` property to `RightToLeft.No` as follows:

```
myTextBox.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.No;
```

or, even better, change that property in the `Winforms Designer` so that this will be automatically reflected into the `InitializeComponent()` method.

For more information, head to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.righttoleft(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your text box prints right-to-left. Have a look at this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.righttoleft(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `Textbox` property as `TextBox.RightToLeft` to `RightToLeft.No`